# Find the equation of the line $ r $

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find the equation of the line $ r $ that goes through $ (1, -2,3) $, concurrent with the line
$$\begin{cases}
x=2+3t \\
y=1+2t \\
z= -1 \\
\end{cases}$$

and has orthogonal director vector $ (1, -3,1) $

**Solution:** line r is contained in the plane $(x-1)-3(y+2)+(z-3)=0$

$x-3y+z=10$

Next we find the intersection of the plane and the concurrent line

$2+3t-3(1+2t)-1=10$

$-3t-2=10$

$t=-4, so (-10,-7,-1)$

So line r goes through the points (1,-2,3) and (-10,-7,-1)
$\begin{cases}
x=1-11t \\
y=-2-5t \\
z=3-4t \\
\end{cases}$

How to solve without using plan concepts? (Whatever if it's parametric, symmetrical, vector representation ....)

Comment: Sorry, I read too hastily  the data of the question. I've deleted my comment

Comment: I suppose you're looking for a parametric representation?

Comment: @Bernard Find the line equation without using plane concepts

Comment: There's a problem: l line does not have a single orthogonal vector in dimension $3$.

Comment: Could you explain what are the "plan concepts", which should be avoided?

Comment: @Bernard As long as the representation can be parametric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach:

Let $\vec r=(a,b,c)$ be a directing  vector of the line we search. Its parametric equation is then given by
$$\begin{cases}
x=\phantom{-}1+au,\\ y=-2+bu, \\ z=\phantom{-}3+cu,\end{cases}\quad(u\in\mathbf R).$$
It meets the given line if and only if the linear system (in $t$ and $u$):
$$\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}1+au=2+3t, \\
-2+bu=1+2t, \\
\phantom{-}3+cu= -1,\\
\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}
au-3t=1, \\
 bu-2t=3, \\
cu= -4,\\
\end{cases}$$
has a solution.

Note the last equation implies that $u, c\ne 0$. Also, a directing vector is defined up to a nonzero scalar multiple, so we may choose the value of $c$ to simplify the computation. We'll take $c=4$, so $u=-1$.

Now the orthogonality condition  is
$$a-3b-4=0,$$
whence a linear system for $a$ and $b$
\begin{cases}
a+3t=-1, \\
b+2t=-3, \\
a-3b=4,\\
\end{cases}
which can easily be solved with RREF of the augmented matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If concurrent means intersecting (which to me is confusing) then your solution is fine, I think. The orthogonal plane is correct and the intersecting point too. The parametrised line indeed lies in that plane etc.

I see no issues with it otherwise.

Comment: @amd the orthogonal vector  pins it into the plane he mentions. But just lying in some plane and intersecting some line is not enough to pin down the line uniquely?

Comment: She doesn't have to be parallel to this straight, she's a concurrente

Comment: @MeuluElisson what do you mean by "concurrente"? intersecting?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I want a different solution than this. You see? Which involves more basic concepts

Comment: @MeuluElisson your solution is already very basic.

Comment: Those two pieces of information _in addition to_ the given point on the line are enough to identify it uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

Use the information that you’ve been given directly. The two lines are coincident, so a direction vector of the line that you’re trying to find is $(2+3t,1+2t,-1)-(1,-2,3)$ for some value of $t$. This vector must be orthogonal to $(1,-3,1)$, so set their dot product equal to zero and solve for $t$.

Answer (score 1):

A straight $r$ going through point $(1,-2,3)$ has this parametric form:
$$x = 1 + a·u$$
$$y = -2 + b·u$$
$$z= 3 + c·u$$

If it has intersection with the other given line, then
$$ x = 1 + au = 2+ 3t$$
$$ y= -2 + bu = 1 +2t$$
$$ z= 3 + cu = -1$$

If it has a orthogonal director vector (1,−3,1) then the dot product with $(a,b,c)$ must be $0$
$$ 1·a -3·b + 1·c = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

This approach ends up computing the plane equation implicitly anyways:
Let's write down all we have:
Point: $\mathbf{p}=(1,-2,3)^T$
Line: $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{l}_1,\,\mathbf{a}=(2,2,-1)^T,\,
\mathbf{l}_1=(3,2,0)^T$
The normal vector:  $\mathbf{n}=(1,-3,1)^T$
Thus, $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{p}+v\mathbf{l}_2,\,
\mathbf{l}_2\mathbf{n}=0$ and $\mathbf{p}+v\mathbf{l}_2=\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{l}_1$ is the point.
Now, let's use $\mathbf{l}_2\mathbf{n}=0$ by multiplying
$\mathbf{p}+v\mathbf{l}_2=\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{l}_1$ by $\mathbf{n}$ to get rid of $v\mathbf{l}_2$ -- that's the same thing with the plane.
$(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{a}).\mathbf{n}=t\mathbf{l}_1.\mathbf{n}$
$t=\frac{(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{a}).\mathbf{n}}{\mathbf{l}_1.\mathbf{n}}$ [$=-5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ReplaceAll%5B%28%28p-a%29.n%29%2F%28l.n%29%2C+%7Bp+-%3E+%7B1%2C+-2%2C+3%7D%2C+a+-%3E+%7B2%2C+2%2C+-1%7D%2Cl-%3E%7B3%2C2%2C0%7D%2Cn-%3E%7B1%2C-3%2C1%7D%7D%5D).
So we've got the 2nd point at desired line: $\mathbf{p}_2=\mathbf{a}+\frac{(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{a}).\mathbf{n}}{\mathbf{l}_1.\mathbf{n}}\mathbf{l}_1$ [$=(-13, -8, -1)^T$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ReplaceAll%5Ba%2B%28%28p-a%29.n%29%2F%28l.n%29l%2C+%7Bp+-%3E+%7B1%2C+-2%2C+3%7D%2C+a+-%3E+%7B2%2C+2%2C+-1%7D%2Cl-%3E%7B3%2C2%2C0%7D%2Cn-%3E%7B1%2C-3%2C1%7D%7D%5D) and can write the line as $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{p}+u(\mathbf{p}_2-\mathbf{p})$.
Can you take it from here?
Note, however, $t=-5$ and not $-4$ as in your solution, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.